# Code contract and defensive programming library for .Net 2.0?

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, libraries

Are there any defensive programming libraries (like Code contract , assert libraries for c# .Net 2.0).

Answer (score 3):

You mean other than [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) itself? What's wrong with it?

Because code contracts supports .NET 2.0... or so I guess from this comment on the FAQ:

> If you are not using it (for instance,
>   **you are using .NET 2.0** or 3.5), then
>   you are using the implementation of
>   the contract class supplied in the
>   assembly Microsoft.Contracts.dll and
>   Debug.Assert is called with an
>   appropriate string specifying what
>   kind of failure was encountered